# Detectar camara conectada/ Desconectada C#

Tags: c#

Hola a todos como puedo detectar cuando mi camara web pase de conectada a desconectada y viceversa , estoy usando C#, con el driver de Aforge y el siguiente código fuente:

```
 using  System.IO;
 using  System.Drawing.Imaging;
 using  AForge.Video;
 using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BuscarDispositivos();
    }

    private bool ExistenDispositivos = false;
    private FilterInfoCollection DispositivosDeVideo;
    private VideoCaptureDevice FuenteDeVideo = null;

    private void btnIniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnIniciar.Text == "Iniciar")
        {
            if (ExistenDispositivos)
            {
                FuenteDeVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(DispositivosDeVideo[cboDispositivos.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
                FuenteDeVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NuevoFrame);
                FuenteDeVideo.Start();
                btnIniciar.Text = "Detener";
                cboDispositivos.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Error: No se encuentra dispositivo.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (FuenteDeVideo.IsRunning)
            {
                TerminarFuenteDeVideo();
                btnIniciar.Text = "Iniciar";
                cboDispositivos.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void CargarDispositivos(FilterInfoCollection Dispositivos)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Dispositivos.Count; i++)
            cboDispositivos.Items.Add(Dispositivos[i].Name.ToString()); //cboDispositivos es nuestro combobox
        cboDispositivos.Text = cboDispositivos.Items[0].ToString();
    }

    public void BuscarDispositivos()
    {
        DispositivosDeVideo = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        if (DispositivosDeVideo.Count == 0)
            ExistenDispositivos = false;
        else
        {
            ExistenDispositivos = true;
            CargarDispositivos(DispositivosDeVideo);
        }
    }

    public void TerminarFuenteDeVideo()
    {
        if (!(FuenteDeVideo == null))
            if (FuenteDeVideo.IsRunning)
            {
                FuenteDeVideo.SignalToStop();
                FuenteDeVideo = null;
            }
    }

    private void video_NuevoFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap Imagen = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pbFotoUser.Image = Imagen;
    }
```

Nota: No necesariamente debe ser Aforge, puede ser cualquier otro SDK

Comment: Ese es el codigo que intentaste para tu pregunta? Por que no te funciona? da fallo? Explica mejor tu situacion

Comment: la idea es que me muestre una alerta cuando la camara sea desconectada, lo demas funciona...

Comment: Repito: en tu codigo está el metodo o funcion que detecte el estado de la camara? de ser asi, te da fallo? Si no tienes el metodo, es que no lo has intentado primero? Que hay de la documentacion?

Comment: Por lo que leo estas buscando un evento de monitoreo del estado del dispositivo en uso el cual al momento de perder la señal levante una bandera la cual puedas usar como señal de evento para mostrar el mensaje de desconexion.

Comment: @lois6b no existe tal evento, lo que puedo hacer mediante un timer, estar monitoreando el evento BuscarDispositivos()